# Hide Silverlight DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

How do I bind the datagrid visibility using MVVM so that if there is no data, set the visibility of the DataGrid to `Collapsed`, in such a way that the code could be reusable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ViewModel expose property like

```cs
// In setter consider INotifyPropertyChanged 
public bool IsDataAvailable
{
  get; set;
}
```

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding IsDataAvailable, 
                      Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Some useful links:

- [How to declare and use BooleanToVisibilityConverter in my View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050816/using-converter-with-image-within-datagrid/8050901#8050901)
- [Good examples of the BooleanToVisibilityConverter implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/534575/485076)
- [WPF MVVM INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation - Model or ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5285377/485076)

Comment: I have tried using that but only works the first time the grid is loaded (i put a break point to monitor that and only gets hit the first time) If i click the search button, the break point does not get hit. Does this has to do with the fact that the VISIBILITY property is not a dependency property?

Comment: I believe because you've not supported INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel, search StackOverflow regarding INotifyPropertyChanged and cusotm properties, for instance [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285377/wpf-mvvm-inotifypropertychanged-implementation-model-or-viewmodel)

Comment: I did implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Is there a working sample that shows the visibility working when clicking a search button to get data on the datagrid? The visibility is not like the ItemsSource property.

Comment: Anyone who did show/hide datagrid if items source is null using a behavior?

Comment: @user282807 : which behaviour you mean?

Comment: I am using MVVM, and my scenario is that i have a search screen and would like to create a behavior for the datagrid, if there is no data then the datagrid behavior would set the visibilty of the datagrid to not show up.